# Rust macro that counts and generates repetitive struct fields

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I want to write a macro that generates varying structs from an integer argument. For example, `make_struct!(3)` might generate something like this:

```
pub struct MyStruct3 {
    field_0: u32,
    field_1: u32,
    field_2: u32
}
```

What's the best way to transform that "3" literal into a number that I can use to generate code? Should I be using `macro_rules!` or a `proc-macro`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a procedural attribute macro and quite a bit of pipework. An example implementation is on [Github](https://github.com/srenauld/so_58246366_proc_macro); bear in mind that it is pretty rough around the edges, but works pretty nicely to start with.

The aim is to have the following:

```
#[derivefields(u32, "field", 3)]
struct MyStruct {
     foo: u32
}
```

transpile to:

```
struct MyStruct {
   pub field_0: u32,
   pub field_1: u32,
   pub field_2: u32,
   foo: u32
}
```

To do this, first, we're going to establish a couple of things. We're going to need a `struct` to easily store and retrieve our arguments:

```
struct MacroInput {
    pub field_type: syn::Type,
    pub field_name: String,
    pub field_count: u64
}
```

The rest is pipework:

```
impl Parse for MacroInput {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        let field_type = input.parse::<syn::Type>()?;
        let _comma = input.parse::<syn::token::Comma>()?;
        let field_name = input.parse::<syn::LitStr>()?;
        let _comma = input.parse::<syn::token::Comma>()?;
        let count = input.parse::<syn::LitInt>()?;
        Ok(MacroInput {
            field_type: field_type,
            field_name: field_name.value(),
            field_count: count.base10_parse().unwrap()
        })
    }
}
```

This defines `syn::Parse` on our `struct` and allows us to use `syn::parse_macro_input!()` to easily parse our arguments.

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn derivefields(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = syn::parse_macro_input!(attr as MacroInput);
    let mut found_struct = false; // We actually need a struct
    item.into_iter().map(|r| {
        match &r {
            &proc_macro::TokenTree::Ident(ref ident) if ident.to_string() == "struct" => { // react on keyword "struct" so we don't randomly modify non-structs
                found_struct = true;
                r
            },
            &proc_macro::TokenTree::Group(ref group) if group.delimiter() == proc_macro::Delimiter::Brace && found_struct == true => { // Opening brackets for the struct
                let mut stream = proc_macro::TokenStream::new();
                stream.extend((0..input.field_count).fold(vec![], |mut state:Vec<proc_macro::TokenStream>, i| {
                    let field_name_str = format!("{}_{}", input.field_name, i);
                    let field_name = Ident::new(&field_name_str, Span::call_site());
                    let field_type = input.field_type.clone();
                    state.push(quote!(pub #field_name: #field_type,
                    ).into());
                    state
                }).into_iter());
                stream.extend(group.stream());
                proc_macro::TokenTree::Group(
                    proc_macro::Group::new(
                        proc_macro::Delimiter::Brace,
                        stream
                    )
                )
            }
            _ => r
        }
    }).collect()
}
```

The behavior of the modifier creates a new `TokenStream` and adds our fields **first**. This is *extremely important*; assume that the struct provided is `struct Foo { bar: u8 }`; appending *last* would cause a parse error due to a missing `,`. Prepending allows us to not have to care about this, since a trailing comma in a struct is not a parse error.

Once we have this `TokenStream`, we successively `extend()` it with the generated tokens from `quote::quote!()`; this allows us to not have to build the token fragments ourselves. One gotcha is that the field name needs to be converted to an `Ident` (it gets quoted otherwise, which isn't something we want).

We then return this modified `TokenStream` as a `TokenTree::Group` to signify that this is indeed a block delimited by brackets.

In doing so, we also solved a few problems:

- Since structs without named members (`pub struct Foo(u32)` for example) never actually have an opening bracket, this macro is a no-op for this
- It will no-op any item that isn't a struct
- It will also no-op structs without a member